# What is a wireless crankset?

Tags: crankset

For example this (rather expensive) item: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/sram-srm-powermeter-pro-wireless-bb30-double-chainset/

What is actually wireless about it? Is this for a cadence meter? Wireless shifting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crankset is not wireless, the power meter inside the crankset is wireless, the power meter inside measures your power output and wirelessly transmits the data to a head unit for display near or on your handlebars.

Comment: Well, to be more accurate, just about all cranksets are wireless.  This one just happens to contain a powermeter, which is also wireless. I'm guessing that there may be some cranksets that have power meters that aren't wireless, although I'm not sure how they would be wired without the wiring interfering with the spinning of the cranks.

Comment: Yes most likely all cranksets are wireless. A buddy has an older SRM wired power meter and the wire runs from the head unit to the bottom bracket area to a sensor magnet that is required to be within 3-5mm of the power meter lid (covers the power meter on the cranks), so even this 'wired' power meter is truly a wireless crankset.

Comment: Yeah, I've never had a crankset with wires on it.  Did get some vines wrapped around them a few times, though.